# LINQ throws error on using Regex.Split()

Tags: c#, regex, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

**ERROR**

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

**FOR CODE**

```
var getfrmbid = (from e in _dbEntity.FormNames
         where e.form_id == id & e.type == "Form"
         select new FormsCreationModel
         {
             form_name = e.form_name,
             form_id = e.form_id,
             formfields = (from i in _dbEntity.FormDetails
                           where e.form_id == i.form_id
                           select i).AsEnumerable().Select(x=> new FormDetailsModel()
                           {
                               field_default = x.field_default,
                               field_id = x.field_id,
                               field_mandatory = x.field_mandatory,
                               field_maxlength = x.field_maxlength,
                               field_name = x.field_name,
                               field_type = x.field_type,
                               field_validation = x.field_validation,
                               field_value = Regex.Split(x.field_value, " ^ ").Select(item => new DropDownValue() { DDValue = item }).ToList()
                           }).ToList()

         }).Single();
```

**NOTE**

Error Spot at `field_value` is of type `List<DropDownValue>` in `FormDetailsModel`

`x.field_value` is a `String` and I am converting it into an `String[]` using `Regex.Split()` and then to `List<DropDownValue>` to assign it on `field_value`.

How could I assign `field_value` from `x.field_value` after splitting?

Comment: LINQ to Entities translates your query into SQL, to run it on database. There is no way to translate your regex to proper SQL.

Comment: You're doing a join between `FormNames` and `FormDetails`, and only convering `FormDetails` to an enumerable. That means some part of the query is still in the database, and can't use regex.

Comment: I could understand the situation. But any other suggestions apart from "what I had done" to "what I can do"?

Comment: How about assigning the `field_value` to `x.field_value` and after the query traverse the collection of `formfields` and update the `field_value` fields using the `Regex`expression?

Comment: What happens if you run alone the query that fills in the `formfields` property? The `AsEnumerable` should avoid this problem. Also try to change this `AsEnumerable` to a `ToList` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace

```
 select i).AsEnumerable().Select(x=> new FormDetailsModel()
```

with

```
 select i).ToList().Select(x=> new FormDetailsModel()
```

When you use .ToList(), DB is queried and Select extension runs locally. Otherwise lambda expression is compiled into sql query and clearly SQL doesn't know Regex.Split(). In Linq2Objects you can use that methods since it runs locally. It's important have in mind what LinqTo* you are using.